# Where can I find the dates and places for UX training courses?

Tags: training

I would like to take a professional training of UX and will be glad to know how and where can I find the right dates and places for such events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UX is a very broad topic, so you wouldn't find a single overview of all UX conferences anywhere.

I think Smashing Magazine has the best collection of conferences:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/02/14/upcoming-events-and-conferences-for-designers-and-developers-in-2011/

The list covers the first months of 2011, so most of these conferences are finished, but they usually arrange annual conferences, so visiting the various conference sites should be useful.  Smashing Magazine announced that they would publish a new article that covers the rest of the year.

In addition to visit the conferences that Smashing Magazine lists, you should:
- Google it
- Look for usergroups and meetups (meetup.com, linkedin.com etc)
- Look for courses at univerities near by
- Follow blogs and authors in general

Keep your eyes open, and you will stumble upon several conferances that fits your needs.